# How to use/configure Arangodb with Playframework?

Tags: arangodb

I am working on Playframework with Mongodb, SQL, Postgress, Couchbase
How can I integrate Arangodb

Comment: You question doesn't give much clarity, give some more details for any one to at least to start thinking.

Comment: You can start by reading the docs. Then you can ask stack overflow specific questions you might have

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile there is someone using the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) with Arangodb.

He created a Photo album storage with focus on space saving:
https://github.com/corbantek/play-photostash